# Different functionality depending on type in templated classes

Tags: c++, templates, types

I was originally going to use a template for an Array-style class and just pass it a `char*` or an `int`, but I ran into problems when trying to implement things like:

```
template<Typename T>
class Array {
    void add(T elem) {
        if(size == capacity) expandArr();
        if(T == char*) //g++ threw errors here
            arr[size] = new char[strlen(word) + 1];
            strcpy(arr[size], word);
        else if(T == int) {
            arr[size] = elem;
        }

        size++;
    }
}
```

Is there another way to check for the element type legally? Or should I just separate the two classes and have them be independent?

I was originally trying to use a templated class because both Array types have the same functionality, but there are some fundamental differences in how memory is allocated in this case for `char*`'s and `int`'s.

Comment: `"but some of the return and parameter types are different."` You are using templates aren't you?

Comment: "but I ran into trouble doing different things", can you expatiate on what these things and the associated troubles were? Preferably with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Are you sure that you actually need runtime polymorphism for your design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class template specialisation is overkill in this case – it forces you to duplicate **the whole class** for different types even though ~90% of the functionality is going to be identical.

The key is to isolate those parts that differ and to specialise only those. For several reasons it’s easier to use overloading rather than specialisation, though.

The differing part in your case is only the assignment of a value to an array item.

```
template <typename T>
class Array {
    void add(T elem) {
        if(size == capacity) expandArr();
        assignItem(elem);
        size++;
    }

    template <typename U>
    void assignItem(U elem) {
        arr[size] = elem;
    }

    void assignItem(char* elem) {
        // Incidentally, DON’T DO THIS! It leaks. Use RAII!
        arr[size] = new char[strlen(elem) + 1];
        strcpy(arr[size], word);
    }
};
```

Of course now you’ve hard-coded the supported types of `Array`: only types with a copy constructor *and* `char*` are supported, no other types. In general you don’t want this restriction, you want to support *arbitrary* types and allow them to specify how they are copied<sup>1</sup>.

There are several ways of achieving this. I’ll just illustrate one here, via a trait class that specifies how a type is copied.

```
template <typename T>
struct CopyConstruct {
    void assign(T& target, T source) const {
        target = source;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename Copy = CopyConstruct<T>>
class Array {
    Copy copier;

    void add(T elem) {
        if(size == capacity) expandArr();
        copier.assign(arr[size], elem);
        size++;
    }
};
```

This class can be used identically to your initial class. For `char*`, the user has two choices: either specialise `CopyConstruct`, or provide a completely own trait when instantiating `Array`, like so:

```
struct CopyCString {
    void assign(char*& target, char* source) const {
        target = new char[strlen(elem) + 1];
        strcpy(arr[size], word);
    }
};

// And then:

Array<char*, CopyCString> strArray;
```

(And note that we’re passing a *reference* to a pointer here – otherwise the assigned memory would be lost because we’d assign the pointer to a *copy* of the array item, not the item itself.)

---

<sup>1</sup> But in fact C++ already uses the copy constructor for exactly that purpose. **The real solution** isn’t any of the above, it’s to wrap `char*` into a copyable type such as `std::string`.

Comment: This is a better answer for the example given.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [template specialisation](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html) to have different behaviour for different template types.

Change your code to this:

```
template<typename T>
class Array {
    void add(T elem) {
        if(size == capacity) expandArr();

        size++;
    }
}

template<>
class Array<char*> {
    void add(T elem) {
        if(size == capacity) expandArr();
        arr[size] = new char[strlen(word) + 1];
        strcpy(arr[size], word);

        size++;
    }
}

template<>
class Array<int> {
    void add(T elem) {
        if(size == capacity) expandArr();
        arr[size] = elem;

        size++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s probably easier to use overloading than template specialisation here.

Comment: @Cong Xu This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Konrad - How would overloading work in this case though? Would the overloaded function go in a separate class for each array type?

Comment: @Taylor See my own answer.